# Image as a background of a canvas dissapears when trying to draw on it

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

I'm trying to write a code to write a polygon on a "preview image" for an type file input. The problem: when I click on the canvas to draw the first point of the polygon, the image dissapears.., why?

```js
$(function() {
    $('#file-input').change(function(e) {
        var file = e.target.files[0],
            imageType = /image.*/;
        
        if (!file.type.match(imageType))
            return;
        
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = fileOnload;
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        
    });
    
    function fileOnload(e) {
        var $img = $('<img>', { src: e.target.result });
        var canvas = $('#canvas')[0];
        context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        $img.load(function() {
            context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);

        });
    }
});

    $.fn.canvasAreaDraw = function (options) {

        this.each(function (index, element) {
            init.apply(element, [index, element, options]);
        });

    }
    
    
    var init = function (index, input, options) {

        var points, activePoint, settings;
        var $canvas, ctx, image;
        var draw, mousedown, stopdrag, move, resize, reset, rightclick, record;
     
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(input).after('<br>', $canvas, '<br>');
            $('canvas').on('mousedown', mousedown);
            $('canvas').on('mouseup', stopdrag);
            context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        });

        points = [];
        
        mousedown = function (e) {
            
            var x, y, dis, lineDis, insertAt = points.length;  //points length = numero de puntos

            if (!e.offsetX) {
                e.offsetX = (e.pageX - $(e.target).offset().left);
                e.offsetY = (e.pageY - $(e.target).offset().top);
            }
            x = e.offsetX;
            y = e.offsetY;

            points.splice(insertAt, 0, Math.round(x), Math.round(y));
            draw();

            return false;
        }
        
        draw = function () {

            context.canvas.width = context.canvas.width;

            context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
            context.fillStyle = 'rgb(255,255,255)' //color background punto
            context.strokeStyle = 'rgb(255,20,20)';
            context.lineWidth = 1;

            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(points[0], points[1]);
            
            for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i += 2) {
                alert("1111");
                context.fillRect(points[i] - 2, points[i + 1] - 2, 4, 4);
                context.strokeRect(points[i] - 2, points[i + 1] - 2, 4, 4);
             
                if (points.length > 2 && i > 1) {
                    context.lineTo(points[i], points[i + 1]);
                }
            }
            
            context.closePath();
            context.stroke(); //dibuja la linea entre los puntos

        };
    }
    
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('canvas').canvasAreaDraw();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="500px" height="300px"></canvas>
<input type="file" id="file-input">
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are clearing the canvas with this line:

```
context.canvas.width = context.canvas.width;
```

Just replace this line with `drawImage()` where you redraw the image onto the canvas instead of clearing it.

Any points that is stored must be redrawn as well each time.

Comment: I have replaced `context.canvas.width = context.canvas.width` with `drawImage()`, and the image is kept but the points are not drawn..

Comment: @ziiweb you need to redraw those too. With canvas all "book-keeping" is manual. Updated answer

Comment: @ KenFyrstenberg sorry, but I dont't know exactly where should I redraw the points..

Comment: @ziiweb you need to store the points, when adding a new store that to, redraw image to canvas, render all current points. But this would be out of scope for the question which asks about the image disappearing. I would suggest opening a new question for that problem.

Comment: as fas as I know, I think that I'm doing already what you say. Look at the `for` inside the `draw()` function, in my opinion that code is rendering the current points

Comment: @ziiweb ah, I forgot to mention this one - remove this line `context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';` Render using "source-over" (default)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73964/discussion-between-ziiweb-and-ken-fyrstenberg).